# IE9 Acceptheader breaks when CSS is rewritten to PHP file

Tags: css, apache2, http-headers, internet-explorer-9

My application relies entirely on mod_rewrite rewriting image / JS / CSS urls to PHP documents with the filename in one of the arguments.

E.g:
/account/accountname/path/to/file
rewrites to: /account/accountname.php?fileName=/path/to/file

php will respond with the correct mimetype and file.

To be ahead of the obvious question: why don't you rewrite directly to the file:
Can't be done, the PHP file responds with a different filecontents per account (versioning), and the only place the 'version dir' is known, is in the PHPfile itself.

Now, this works in every browser, except for IE9. They apparently send a requestheader containing an accept-header which only matches text/css (where FF4 still matches text/css, */*). Seems fine, except that apache refuses to parse the PHP document before it receives the mime-header. I just can't figure out how to make apache parse the CSS file, and only respond to the acceptheader AFTER parsing the file (or not at all, allso fine with me)

Hope someone has the answer.. Would help a great deal
Thanks in advance!

Tim

Comment: re the 'obvious question' you addressed: when it comes to CSS and JS files, it is good to have static elements of the site served from static files rather than via PHP because of the server overhead of running everything through PHP. It also removes any possibility of caching, which has further dramatic impacts on site performance. You should separate the static parts of your CSS and JS and simply serve them as plain files. The non-dynamic aspects can still be run separately through PHP, but you probably want to keep dynamic CSS content to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The mod you want is called X-SendFile.  When used from within a PHP file, it allows the Apache engine to serve up the final file as if it was requested directly:

You simply need to download and enable mod_xsendfile on your host.

An article: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/

Example:

```
// Look up ABSOLUTE PATH to file, etc
$file_path = ...
header("X-Sendfile: $file_path");
exit();
```

This will tell Apache to serve the file under $file_path directly.  No muss, no fuss!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with my Serendipity Blog engine. IE10 was not accepting the CSS file created from PHP because of the rewrite rule. Adding [...,T=text/css] to the rewrite rule in .htaccess solved the Problem for me.

```
RewriteRule ^(serendipity\.css|serendipity_admin\.css) index.php?url=/$1 [L,QSA,T=text/css]
```